# How can I make Specflow use bindings from external assemblies

Tags: c#, binding, attributes, nuget, specflow

I have a project which makes use of binding attributes. I decided to package some of the logic that is used in these bindings so that this can be shared in multiple projects.

After packaging the NuGet package and referencing it, the bindings do not seem to be triggering at all from the package. When hovering over the `[Binding]` keyword, there's no referenced namespace and the text is in white.

Is it possible to have `BindingAttribute` recognized in a NuGet package at all?

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: @user1207289 what part of this question requires code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you tagged `specflow`, I assume this question is really "How can I make Specflow use bindings from external assemblies". A quick google search of that question finds [this page on the Specflow wiki](https://specflow.org/documentation/use-bindings-from-external-assemblies/).

The important part from the page:

> In order to use bindings from an external binding assembly, you have to list it (with the assembly name) in the app.config of the SpecFlow project. The SpecFlow project is always included implicitly. See more details on the configuration in the `<stepAssemblies>` section of [the configuration guide](https://specflow.org/documentation/Configuration/).
>
> ```xml
> <specFlow>
>   <stepAssemblies>
>     <stepAssembly assembly="MySharedBindings" />
>   </stepAssemblies>
> </specFlow>
> ```

Otherwise, NuGet doesn't do anything special, it's just a delivery mechanism. By the time the compiler runs, it doesn't know whether each assembly was from a project or package reference. At runtime it's irrelevant.

It's common for libraries like MVC or Specflow to only discover classes from the calling assembly, not all assemblies, so you usually have to read the docs of the framework you're using to find out how to register additional assemblies. There is no single or common way, each library or framework has its own technique.

Comment: Thank you! Must have missed this part of the documentation and thought that maybe it's not possible at all yet. This solution worked fine for me.